# How to save checkbox state using cookies in an infowindow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, cookies, checkbox

I have multiple markers which are loaded on window load and I am dynamically creating data for each info window.

All the infowindows of marker contains checkboxes. How can I save the state of checkbox and then display the state when the info window is clicked (also the data in info window should be loaded when the marker is clicked).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at document.cookie, this should solve your problem.
This is what i use:

```
// CLASS LocalStorage
function LocalStorage()
{
}

LocalStorage.prototype.AsObj = function() {

    var obj = {};
    var arr = document.cookie.split("; ");
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        var tmp = arr[i].split("=");
        obj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }

    return obj;
};

LocalStorage.prototype.AddCookie = function(key, val) {
    document.cookie = key + '=' + val;
};

LocalStorage.prototype.RemoveCookie = function(key) {
    document.cookie = key + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;'
};
```

Please note that this code is not perfect and my javascript can not exactly be called good.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp):

**Give each checkbox an unique id (HTML):**

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-box-id="###">
```

**If a checkbox is checked/unchecked save that in LocalStorage (jQuery):**

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    var chckd = this.checked ? 'true' : 'false';
    var index = $(this).data('box-id');
    localStorage.setItem(index, chckd);
});
```

**On document load or whenever you want, load the checked Boxes from LocalStorage and check them (jQuery):**

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkbox').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).data('box-id');
        if (localStorage.getItem(index) == 'true') {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });    
});
```

You can also do this with cookies, but i think that requires a plugin for jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve the same problem. 
My script hides columns based on checkbox, but each time page is reloaded it shows column again.

How to add cookie to this?

```
    $(function () {

        var $chk = $("#grpChkBox input:checkbox"); 
        var $tbl = $("#register");
        var $tblhead = $("#register th");

        $chk.prop('checked', true); 


        $chk.click(function () {
            var colToHide = $tblhead.filter("." + $(this).attr("name"));
            var index = $(colToHide).index();
            $tbl.find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').toggle();


        });
    });
</script>
```

Checkbox code:

> > ```
> >  <div id="grpChkBox">
> >     <p><input type="checkbox" name="nabavna"/> NC</p>
> > ```